# Getting mercurial "hg commit" to work with Notepad++

Tags: mercurial, notepad++, dvcs

I just replaced notepad with notepad++ using [NotepadReplacer](http://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/) and now my `hg commit` isn't working correctly.

Before replacing Notepad, `hg commit` would launch a new text file for me to enter my commit message into. With Notepad++, I'm prompted to create the file, and mercurial aborts the commit because of an empty commit message.

I know I can enter the message inline with the `hg commit` with the `-m` option, but I'd like to have the option of entering the commit message in the text file. I like having the status displayed in the text file as context for the commit message without having to type `hg stat` before `hg commit`.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Didn't even think of asking this here; I'd just resigned myself to using Notepad++ for everything *but* this!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try placing in your `%USERPROFILE%\.hgrc` (or `%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini`) something along the lines of:

```
[ui]
editor = path/to/notepad++ -multiInst -nosession
```

Perhaps adding a `-notabbar` after `-nosession` could prove useful, too.

Comment: That worked perfectly regardless of whether I had replaced notepad. Grazie!

Comment: Worked for me! I put the path in quotes